# google apps script getas

Tags: google-apps-script

My question relates to the usage of a workaround to the problem of converting a Google Doc to HTML for use as an email template that was published by [Henrique Abreu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222901/henrique-abreu). It's registered as [Issue 585](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=585) on the Google Apps Script issue tracker.

I have been using the following code for the best part of a year now and aside from the ugly authorisation scenario (ie the automatic authorisation system doesn't work) it's been working ok.

```
function getDocAsHtml(docId){
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/Export?exportFormat=html&format=html&id=';
  var auth = googleOAuth_('docs',url+docId);
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+docId,auth).getContentText();
}

function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

My problem is that recently new authorisations no longer work. So existing spreadsheets that I use continue to work and send emails correctly. However having created a new spreadsheet and imported the code into it, the authorisation mechanism is triggered [1].

The problem is that whereas previously when I had granted permissions the debugger authorization dialog would disappear and the system would work, now the dialog simply re-appears. When trying to run the code-path from a menu in the spreadsheet I get a generic "Oops! Authorisation required" dialog instead [1].

Leaving aside the fact that this is an ugly workaround for an issue that's been floating around for a long time now, what's changed to make this workaround no longer work? Is there another solution?

[1] Unfortunately I can't upload images yet but see the [Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=585) where I've attached an image with examples of the error and authorisations dialogs I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question (and your sample spreadsheet) you are using a scope I am not sure will work. The "scope" I use for docs is "https://docs.google.com/feeds/". This is documented here https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/auth/oauth#Scope. Please change the scope you pass to googleOAuth_ in your code and let us know if the problem goes away.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. This is what you get when you try to rationalise code that you have an imprecise understanding of.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen you post on issue tracker and made some test on a new spreadsheet. In my test the authorization process shows up when I use this small function :

```
function autorise(){
// fonction à appeler pour autoriser googleOauth
var id= "put here the string ID of a doc you own"
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
  var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+'download/documents/Export?exportFormat=html&format=html&id='+id,
                              googleOAuth_('docs',url)).getContentText();  
}
// this part is the same you use and is already in your script... I show it here for info only
function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

Maybe you could try it ?

or, if you prefer, test it on [this shared testsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dHVJQ1hVaXV4NmhPQm56dWk2MmVOOHc#gid=0)

Comment: I also can not reproduce this problem. Maybe it is related to the first oAuth authorization being called with an UiApp opened, or something along those lines. Anyway, having to authorize like this, separately and  in the code only is indeed ugly. But that's another issue, 667: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=677

Comment: Thanks Serge. I'm pretty sure that the code you've quoted up there is all but identical to mine so I don't think it's the code that is the problem, I think it's to do with environment. I'm investigating now but I _think_ it's related to two factors; 1) I'm usually logged in using multiple google accounts (the default one not being the one I develop scripts with) and 2) Alternatively I use an incognito window.

Comment: Ok. It's not to do with multiple-sign in and it's not to do with incognito window. The problem relates to the privacy of the document being exported via the API. If it's public or public with link this code works fine. If it's any more private than that, this code will not work, and this behaviour has definitely changed.

Comment: So to be clear, my problem related to the _privacy_ setting of the template document. 

It seems that now the authentication fails unless the source document has been shared either "Public on the Web" or "Anyone with the Link". Any privacy setting greater than this will fail.

I've created a [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/a/lancashirebadgergroup.org.uk/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqGECWg43i78dGVDSFA5T1drNWdlbk53WHhkRTJ0MXc&pli=1#gid=0) to highlight the problem.